# Why do I have to press the shutter button twice to take a photo with my Canon DSLR?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, shutter, canon-70d

I have a problem with my DSLR, a Canon 70D. When I push the shutter button to take a photo, I need to push it once more to take a single shot. The AF mode is not on self-timer.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Is there any chance you have mirror lock up set in the custom functions?

Comment: After that first push, but before the 2nd push to actually take the photo, does the viewfinder go black? If so then yes - you've probably enabled mirror-lock up.

Answer (score 8):

You have probably enabled mirror lockup.

The purpose of mirror lockup is to allow the slight vibrations caused by the movement of the mirror to dissipate before the shutter is opened. This is mostly an issue at shutter times between about 1/100 second and 1 second. Shorter exposures are over before the vibrations reach the parts of the camera that could cause motion blur from the mirror movement. Longer exposures are long enough that the vibrations last only a very short percentage of the total exposure time. Use of mirror lockup is normally accompanied by either the use of a wired cable release or by the use of a wireless remote control so that the camera does not need to be touched directly to release the shutter.

To disable mirror lockup, go into the 70D's menu setting under *Shooting 2* (the second red tab with the little camera symbol). Scroll down to the bottom, select *Mirror Lockup*, change the setting from *enable* to *disable*, and press the *Set* button to apply the change.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it on a Canon 60D

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I did a macro shoot at home, then went night shooting with the double shutter click problem. I also forgot to reset AE settings after a the night shoot. I came home realized I had not turned off the two second timer for which caused the double click problem nor did I reset the AE exposure setting after the night shoot.  Lesson learned- Reset my camera to the basics before and after use.